# How the loss is computed in multi class segmentation problem which has different ground truth and output channels? (UNET, dice loss)

Tags: image-processing, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to understand how loss is computed in the case of UNET to be trained on a dataset having 21 classes (1 mask with 21 different colors, each color denoting a class). So, groud truth shape is N * M * 1 (grayscale image, each pixel value represents the class color (black for the background, green for trees, etc)). But output shape is N*M*21 (it returns 21 images of the same size as input). My question is, how loss is computed in such scenarios? when you have the target shape of N * M * 1 and output shape (predicted tensor) is N * M * 21.

My interpretation is, N * M is the prediction image for each class label (1st N * M prediction image for the 0th(let's say background) label, 2nd N * M prediction image for the 1st label (let's say trees) and so on. Somewhat like one vs rest approach.

I am using UNET implemented in this library [segmentation_models](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models).
I am really confused, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is good.

Practically the masks(ground truth ys) are created in such a way that, if you have K classes, then you would have K matrices of dimension H x W.

Suppose that you have as a problem a segmentation of trees, pedestrians and cars. Here K = 3, and the input mask for trees, for example, is a matrix with dimension H x W, where the ground truth is marked with 1 only where the trees are, and with 0 otherwise. Then, for the second mask which corresponds to the pedestrians, the ground truth is marked with 1 only where the pedestrians are, and with 0 otherwise. This is the manner in which we are constructing the dataset, due to the fact that we have **multi-class segmentation** and not **multi-label segmentation**, where overlapping of 1's on different masks is possible.

Yes, it is true that the input images are grayscale like you described, with values between [0,number_of_classes], yet the network does not receive that input ground truth like you might suspect.

In fact, if you look closely at these lines of code from the tutorial (same is both for Keras and PyTorch), you can see the following snippet:

```
# extract certain classes from mask (e.g. cars)
masks = [(mask == v) for v in self.class_values]
mask = np.stack(masks, axis=-1).astype('float')
```

in which the process I described above takes place.

Now that we have this in place, proceeding to the loss function is simple: it works as if you had only one mask with 1s and 0s, but it is adapted to the H x W x K situation instead of H x W x K.

Having in mind that:

> ```
>     gt: ground truth 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
>     pr: prediction 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
> ```

by inspecting those lines of code, you will solve your dilemma:

```
backend = kwargs['backend']

gt, pr = gather_channels(gt, pr, indexes=class_indexes, **kwargs)
pr = round_if_needed(pr, threshold, **kwargs)
axes = get_reduce_axes(per_image, **kwargs)

# score calculation
intersection = backend.sum(gt * pr, axis=axes)
union = backend.sum(gt + pr, axis=axes) - intersection

score = (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)
score = average(score, per_image, class_weights, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your time to answer my doubts. I have accepted your answer and upvoted it.

Comment: You are welcome, I have been in this situation some time ago and I know how good it is to have someone point you in the right direction ( I didn't have anyone to help me) :D

Comment: Hi, one last question, How do I visualize the predicted tensor? The prediction will be of shape N * M * 21 where each N * M matrix will have a probability distribution of being that class. In my opinion, I need to set a threshold like if the probability is greater than 0.5 then the class is present, 0 otherwise. Then I stack up all the 21 predicted images, Is this the right approach?

Comment: yes, practically for one pixel you have an array 1 x 1 x K, where K = 0 probability for Tree, K = 1 probability for pedestrian etc.

Comment: We are talking about a cube practically, but in essence since it's only one pixel it's 1x1xK which amounts to a 1D-array :D